# Pledge fullfilled status?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I pledged to get this site started, and I'm pretty sure I fullfilled my promise already. But there is no indication I noticed in my member page saying anything about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On MESE, you have the beta badge (https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/123/vonbrand?tab=badges)

On Area 51, you have a fulfilled commitment listed for MESE, as well as the 'Upholder' badge (http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/78078/vonbrand).

Are there more badges/other achievements to get?

Comment: "Actively participated in beta" isn't the same as "fullfilled the pledge", AFAIU. Hadn't looked ar Area51. Thanks!

Comment: @vonbrand: Were you looking for something else, too? I wasn't sure if my answer is the pledge-thing you were looking for.